# how to set Internal Variables in mailx in linux?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, mailx

`save` internal variable enable saving of messages in the `dead.letter` file on interrupt or delivery error.The default is save.

problem: default is `save` so `dead.letter` file is created at `home` directory,
expected: I want to change the value of `save` variable so file will not be generated

I tried `set save=false;`, but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man page for my `mailx` says a lot of things about `set nosave` and so on,
but they dont seem to work.  The only way to stop your dead.letter file
growing I have found is to replace it by a link to the special file `/dev/null`.

```
rm ~/dead.letter
ln -s /dev/null ~/dead.letter
```

Comment: its works for me but how to undo this thing :), i think removing of dead.letter file is not best practice, it would be helpfull for me if provide set environment variable syntex

Comment: @GirdharSinghRathore Like you I could not find any syntax that had any effect at all.

Comment: can you please provide undo syntext for 

rm ~/dead.letter

ln -s /dev/null ~/dead.letter?

Comment: @GirdharSinghRathore To undo the link created by `ln` simply do the remove again: `rm ~/dead.letter`. The file will be created by mailx if it is missing and if it wants to save to it.